# Determine branch of Lambert $W$ function

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am solving the equation $3\sqrt{x}=2^x$.
I had convert it to the form of $ye^y=\frac{-\ln 4}{9}$ while $y=-x  \ln 4$
So $W(\frac{-\ln 4}{9})=y$
I know that $y$ is negative, so as the Lambert $W$ function,and $\frac{-\ln 4}{9}$ is between $-e^{-1}$ and $0$
But according to the graph of Lambert $W$ function, a value of $z$ (let say it is $\frac{-\ln 4}{9}$) have two values of $W(z)$.
So, I have to determine which branch of Lambert $W$ function it is to use the suitable approximation.
Is there anyway to determine the branch of Lambert $w$ function without plotting graph? Thanks.

Comment: Why just one branch?  Surely if you graph the original equation, you will find **two** solutions?

Comment: Sorry for my mistake.....After checking Wolfram Alpha it really has 2 solutions...I do this equation originally without plotting the graph so I think that it has 1 solution....maybe I should delete the post later...Thanks for clarifiying it.

Comment: No problem. The fact that you reached a point when you had to take the $W$ of a negative number between $-e^{-1}$ and $0$ should alarm you that there are indeed two real solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any reason to choose just one branch.  As you can see by graphing, there are two solutions, denoted by two branches.

[image]

As far as approximating them, you may note that for $-e^{-1}<x<0$, we have

$$W_0(x)\approx x\exp(-x\exp(-x\exp(-x\exp(-x))))$$

Of course, just throw in more exponentials to get higher accuracy.

$$W_{-1}(x)\approx\ln(-x)+\ln(-\ln(-x)+\ln(-\ln(-x)+\ln(-\ln(-x))))$$

Or if you don't want to use this lengthy iteration formula, then

$$-1-\sqrt{2t}-t<W_{-1}(-e^{-t-1})<-1-\sqrt{2t}-\frac23t$$

Particularly, you'll want

$$-e^{-t-1}=-\frac19\ln(4)\\e^{-t-1}=\frac19\ln(4)\\-(t+1)=\ln(\ln(4))-\ln(9)\\t=-1+\ln(9)-\ln(\ln(4))$$

Comment: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.paper.edu.cn/scholar/downpaper/liling116674-201210-19&ved=0ahUKEwi5oqTRr8_VAhXLPY8KHbHUDME4ChAWCC4wAg&usg=AFQjCNHKM-57WSeedC8D1bvFcrdj_JiQRw I use this to approximate..